# Why can't I push tags in GitHub workflows anymore, and how do I fix it?

Tags: git, github-actions, git-tag, shallow-clone

My team has a GitHub release workflow that automatically tags our prod branch on push. It has been working fine for the last year, with the most recent success being May 2, 2022. This workflow failed on May 11, 2022, and now I can't figure out how it ever worked. There was a new release of git on May 5, but I've looked through the changes and nothing is screaming obvious.

The error is:

```
Run git push --tags
  git push --tags
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.12/x64/lib
To github.com:ORGANIZATION/PACKAGE.git
 ! [remote rejected] PACKAGE/v0.3.13 -> PACKAGE/v0.3.13 (shallow update not allowed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:ORGANIZATION/PACKAGE.git'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Here is a minimum example of the workflow step that is failing:

```
  check:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: correct_repository
    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_MACHINE_SSH }}
      - name: Set up Python 3.8
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8
      - name: Install bump2version
        run: python -m pip install bump2version
      - name: Extract package version
        id: package
        run: |
          echo -n "::set-output name=version::"
          bump2version --dry-run --list patch | grep ^current_version | sed -r s,"^.*=",,
      - name: Tag package
        run: git tag PACKAGE/v${{ steps.package.outputs.version }}
      - name: Publish tags
        run: git push --tags 
    outputs:
      package-version: ${{ steps.package.outputs.version }}
```

The actual step is somewhat more complicated, but the above fails when I simulate it locally by copy-pasting the shell commands in order from the workflow log.

As far as I can tell, by default [actions/checkout](https://github.com/actions/checkout) makes a shallow clone of the repository with depth 1, and has done so for quite some time (the last successful run specifies depth 1). You're not supposed to be able to push from shallow clones, since [it is unclear how "push into/from a shallow repo" should behave](https://git-scm.com/docs/shallow).

It makes sense that this workflow should fail, but:

- Why did it succeed before the 2.36.1 release of git (or is that release unrelated)?
- What are the recommended checkout parameters if I want to push tags from a workflow?
- Is this by any chance fixed in actions/checkout@v3?

Comment: GitHub action `checkout@v2` makes a shallow clone; GitHub action `checkout@v1` makes (or made?) a full clone. As far as I know there was no update to the shallow-clone push code in 2.36.1, so it's most likely just a case of luck (whether that's good or bad luck that it worked by accident until now, is your choice). Use a deeper clone, or a full (non-shallow) clone.

Comment: A new Git version would not have affected you, since the virtual environment for the GitHub action would not immediately reflect that new git version. In fact, there was an update to the `ubuntu-latest` environment on May 5: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/pull/5474 . That seems like the most likely reason that this behavior suddenly stopped working on this day, but I doubt it's worth looking into. That update also didn't touch `git`.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, thanks to [@torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) and [@TonyArra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81216/tonyarra) in the comments above pointing to the solution and easing my mind about what may have actually changed to start crashing the workflow. Ultimate fix to increase the fetch depth configured for actions/checkout:

```
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          ssh-key: ${{ secrets.CMU_DELPHI_DEPLOY_MACHINE_SSH }}
          fetch-depth: 5
```